# EJB Timer Table Columns

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb-timer

Do you know if there is a documentation regarding the ejb timer table columns?

- "TIMERID"
- "APPLICATIONID"
- "BLOB"
- "CONTAINERID"
- "CREATIONTIMERAW"
- "INITIALEXPIRATIONRAW"
- "INTERVALDURATION"
- "LASTEXPIRATIONRAW"
- "OWNERID"
- "PKHASHCODE"
- "SCHEDULE"
- "STATE"

Specifically, what kind of information does each of these columns reflect in detail. E.g. what information is stored in the BLOB column?

Since I found no description on this topic maybe one of you can help here or provide a good website to get these information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These details are not defined by the Java EE specifications and are therefore vendor dependent.

If you're using one of the open source servers (such as GlassFish, Payara, TomEE or WildFly) then you can trawl through their source code to see how these columns are used.

Comment: Hm... Ok, not the answer I hope to get but I'm fine with this, too. It's good to know that it's different between the servers.

I'm using the glassfish server, so I'll have a look. Thanks!